# How could Madara absorb the Divine tree?

Tags: naruto

In the anime Madara absorbs the Divine Tree with his rinnegan. How did he do that? Does Madara's rinnegan have the same powers of absorbing as Obito's Mangekyo Sharingan or is it just a plot-hole?

Comment: I dont think there is a real answer for that, but i would guess it was because its part of the body of the 10 tails, and he had the 10 tails chakra inside of himself. Rinnegan can also allow the user to perform almost any jutsu

Comment: Think of the tree as a form of energy, chakra, rather than an actual tree. Because, that is the true nature of the God Tree. Therefore, Madara can absorb chakra using his Rinnegan.

Comment: There is no exact answer for this question but according to me it must be as similar as absorbing chakra.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, but it seems illogical to me that the tree was absorbed while in the tree state not as 10 tails.

Comment: @Ero Sennin I can't imagine it as something else than a tree or part of 10 tails. But chakra no... I don't think so... it was't a jutsu after all.

Comment: The Tailed Beasts aren't a jutsu. But they're just pure chakra. All the beasts are pure chakra and they were created by splitting the Ten Tails. So the Ten Tails is completely an entity composed of pure chakra. The god tree brought forth in the Fourth Shinobi War is the Ten Tails' final form. Therefore, it is a chakra composition and not an actual tree. If you need further clarification, I could make an answer.

Comment: @Ero Sennin I understood now. Thanks. I didn't know that the beasts are pure chakra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not the Rinnegan that absorbed the divine tree/ten-tails; it's the jutsu Madara weaved that summoned it. Obito did the same thing too to become the ten-tails jinchuriki.

Take a look at these pictures from the anime and manga for yourself:

[Episode 414 (On the Brink of Death)](http://kissanime.to/Anime/Naruto-Shippuuden/Episode-414?id=109857)
[image]

[Chatper 663 (Absolutely)](http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Naruto/Naruto-663?id=290897)
[image]

Second, Obito's Mangekyo Sharingan allows him to absorb objects into another dimension. Madara is absorbing the ten-tails into himself. There's a difference. Therefore, it's not a plot hole.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact answer for your question, but it appears that the God Tree willed itself to be absorbed by Madara as mentioned in the [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/God_Tree).

> Just before Madara Uchiha absorbed the Ten-Tails into himself, a voice spoke to him, willing him to "Absorb me. The God Tree… the Ten-Tails. Absorb everything."

and in addition..

> In the anime, the God Tree is shown to have a will of its own..

And also, I've read above comments which is agreeable that since Madara became the vessel of the Ten-tails, he could have been able to absorb the Tree.

**But no specific jutsu was mentioned.**